# Must Java be installed to run a Java application?

Tags: java

when you write an app in java, people need to have this [java](http://www.java.com/en/) installed to use it right?

Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: A JRE has to be available. Normally this is installed separately. However, there are exceptions. For instance, see [bundling with 7zip/sfx](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/10/bundle-java-the-jre-and-launch-a-java-app-with-7zip-sfx.html) Or consider an Android/Dalvik platform which takes a Java bytecode (e.g. compiled Java) and runs it on a "Java-like" platform (it doesn't use Java bytecode during execution and is thus not strictly a JRE). Note: If a JRE is bundled with an application, sizes can be drastically reduced with use of ProGuard, etc. Not sure about redist legality though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Traroth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770345/do-people-have-to-install-java-to-use-an-app-written-in-java/4770356#4770356) is correct; your audience needs the Java Runtime in order to use your java.

However, they don't necessarily need *that* Java, or in other words, they don't need to be using Sun (now Oracle)'s JRE. They could also be using the [OpenJDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK), or any of the other [free java implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Java_implementations).

Not a silly question at all.

---

Side Note: As [Glenn Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770345/must-java-be-installed-to-run-a-java-application/4770455#4770455) stated, there are Ahead-Of-Time compilers, and if you want to go down that route, go ahead. But I'd strongly warn against jumping into that boat, especially if you are just starting off in Java. AOT Java compilers come with their own set of issues.

Comment: @Glenn Nelson I'm 60% sure that something compiled for Sun's JRE should at least be able to try run with the OpenJDK. There may be some issues between implementation, but that's a whole different issue.

Comment: What I'm getting at is how you compile your source. Anyway what is wrong with using AOT? I know GCJ has basically no support but JET works extremely well.

Comment: @Glenn Nelson I'm not implying that it's wrong. What I am saying is that AOT java compilation is not a silver bullet for distributing your java app, and comes with its own unique issues -- plus, I believe JET still [requires Excelsior's Runtime](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/jetfaq.html#not). Since it is another valid solution, that's why I acknowledged your answer :-).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need the Java Runtime to run a java program:

http://java.com/en/download/

Comment: I don't think he's speaking about Android programs or native GCJ programs if he doesn't even know the JRE. Thank you for your input...

Comment: I want to apologize for being a dick. I just had one of those bad days and snapped and took it out on you.

Comment: @Glenn Nelson: Ok, no problem. Apologies are rare enough on the net to be pointed out. Everything cool on my side! Everybody can have a bad day. Hope things are better for you, now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are also executable installers which may bundle Java or download it during the installation. You may also use "Java Web Start".

Comment: But, the person launching your WebStart application will still need to have a JRE installed, just as with a "normal" Java application.

Comment: I don't think so: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/javawebstart/AutoInstall.html But I've never tried.

Comment: That article is non-sense. I have never seen this auto-install work. I really mean never. Sure, it'll probably work for others, but all my tests with Firefox and Chrome always failed: if I didn't have a JRE (or the incorrect version) installed, it always links to the download site and instructs me to manually install a JRE. Try it yourself (I just did... again: no auto install).

Comment: I re-read it quickly and it looks like it should do the install itself only with IE, otherwise it can check if you have the proper version and let you do it manually. It's better than nothing... slightly.